# Issue with nested loops in Ruby

Tags: ruby, graph, nested-loops

So I right now I have a list of edges of a graph. With this list, I'm trying to build a adjacency map, in which its key is an edge and the value is a list of edges that are adjacent to the edge. I'm using a nested loop that compares each edge in the list to every other edge in the list. However, this is not building a map that I expect it to. Below is my code:

```
def build_adjacency
        @paths.each do |start_path|
            @paths.each do |end_path|
                # 3 cases for edge adcency
                if (start_path.end_node == end_path.start_node) || (start_path.start_node == end_path.end_node) || (start_path.start_node == end_path.start_node)
                    if @adjacency_map.has_key?("#{start_path}".to_s)
                        @adjacency_map[:"#{start_path}".to_s] << end_path
                    else
                        value = [end_path]
                        @adjacency_map[:"#{start_path}".to_s] = value
                    end
                end
            end
        end
end
```

I also tried `array.combination` but that is not working either. Thank you for the help.

Test input: (start node, end node, color, type)

```
A B R C
B E B C
B C B T
C D G T
```

Output for @adjacency_map:

```
C:\Users\Jin\Documents\Mines\Algorithms (CSCI 406)\Project_3>ruby graph.rb
Key: A B R C    Value: [#<Path:0x2548a28 @start_node="A", @end_node="B", @color=
"R", @type="C">, #<Path:0x2548968 @start_node="B", @end_node="E", @color="B", @t
ype="C">, #<Path:0x25488a8 @start_node="B", @end_node="C", @color="B", @type="T"
>, #<Path:0x25487e8 @start_node="C", @end_node="D", @color="G", @type="T">]
Key: B E B C    Value: [#<Path:0x2548a28 @start_node="A", @end_node="B", @color=
"R", @type="C">, #<Path:0x2548968 @start_node="B", @end_node="E", @color="B", @t
ype="C">, #<Path:0x25488a8 @start_node="B", @end_node="C", @color="B", @type="T"
>, #<Path:0x25487e8 @start_node="C", @end_node="D", @color="G", @type="T">]
Key: B C B T    Value: [#<Path:0x2548a28 @start_node="A", @end_node="B", @color=
"R", @type="C">, #<Path:0x2548968 @start_node="B", @end_node="E", @color="B", @t
ype="C">, #<Path:0x25488a8 @start_node="B", @end_node="C", @color="B", @type="T"
>, #<Path:0x25487e8 @start_node="C", @end_node="D", @color="G", @type="T">]
Key: C D G T    Value: [#<Path:0x2548a28 @start_node="A", @end_node="B", @color=
"R", @type="C">, #<Path:0x2548968 @start_node="B", @end_node="E", @color="B", @t
ype="C">, #<Path:0x25488a8 @start_node="B", @end_node="C", @color="B", @type="T"
>, #<Path:0x25487e8 @start_node="C", @end_node="D", @color="G", @type="T">]
```

Comment: Could you also post the input, the output you are getting and expected output? It helps with such details.

Comment: Well, for the input I'm reading in a text file that consists of the edges (start node and end node). And I'm just outputting my entire map to check if it's building the correct map. This is going to be too long to post here. But does my loop structure seem correct, to compare each element of an array to every other element in the array?

Comment: A small example will suffice, like with 2-3 nodes that you may read from file and how that adjacency map should look etc.

Comment: yes, if you want to find an error it is also a good idea to use a small test file.

Comment: I have added test input and output. Please let me know if you see anything wrong. I also need to fix my code so that it doesn't compare two identical edges.

Answer (score 0):

The following is strange:

```
:"#{start_path}".to_s
```

What ever class your object `start_path` is, you convert it to a string via interpolation, than convert it to a symbol, only to then convert it to a string again. You can just use strings as hash keys. And in your call to `has_key?` you have not used the colon. (should normally make no difference)

Also, if you unsure about you implemented the condition correctly, I recommend to create a method to encapsulate it. Especially when the condition has a semantic meaning.

Comment: Without the `to_s`, it wasn't doing the right comparisons (for some reason).  After adding `to_s`, it worked. I'm still not sure why. And I might have fixed my own issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that only problem with your code that it's not checking if `start_path` and `end_path` are the same. So, it adds unnecessary "A-B is adjacent to A-B" into your map.

Maybe you should try just add one line?

```ruby
def build_adjacency
    @paths.each do |start_path|
        @paths.each do |end_path|
            next if start_path == end_path # this one!

            # 3 cases for edge adcency
            if (start_path.end_node == end_path.start_node) || (start_path.start_node == end_path.end_node) || (start_path.start_node == end_path.start_node)
                if @adjacency_map.has_key?("#{start_path}".to_s)
                    @adjacency_map[:"#{start_path}".to_s] << end_path
                else
                    value = [end_path]
                    @adjacency_map[:"#{start_path}".to_s] = value
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Here's my full code, reproducing the solution: https://gist.github.com/zverok/6785c213fd78430cd423